# gitolite users cannot connect

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite

I've got an issue with other users being able to connect to my gitolite server.

Everything is working fine on my end (I'm the admin and also did the `gl-easy-install`) - however, I've requested a `pub` from another user and added it to the `keydir`, along with adding their permissions to the `gitolite-admin` repo in the `conf` file. I `git add` and `commit` those files, and `push` them back up to the gitolite server. Everything looks good.

I told the user to try `git clone git@server.com:gitolite-admin.git` and they get a permission error. The command hooks are in the git user's `authorized_keys` file, so I'm a little confused as to what I'm missing.

I saw in some other answers that the correct address to use is `user@server.com:gitolite-admin.git`, but based on the `authorized_keys` file, that doesn't seem at all correct.

Help is much appreciated, thanks for your expertise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do a `ssh -vvvv git@gitserver.com` on your machine. You will see what keys are offered. Now do the same on this user's machine. Also please post your config file for gitolite and if you have them, the ~/.ssh/config files if you guys have them. Replace your any sensitive repo with something generic.

(upvoted your question)

Comment: quick question while i gather that - will the user i've added be able to connect via `ssh` to the server? i was under the impression that they'd only be able to connect via `git clone`

Comment: yes but through the gitolite account that the server knows about. `ssh git@gitserver.com` shouldn't give you a command prompt but instead list the repositories and log you out immediately.

Comment: ssh -v showed us that it was looking for `id_rsa` and not `username`, which took us both by surprise. is there a way to have it seek out something other than id_rsa?

Comment: @melee: Have the user add a section to their `~/.ssh/config` to configure a key to use with your server: (lines separated by plus) `Host server.com` + `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/other_key_file`. They should then be able to do `git clone git@server.com:gitolite-admin.git`.

Comment: @Chris Johnsen thank you! Doing this gitolite install has taught me far more than I ever wanted to know about ssh.

Answer (score 3):

Usually these problems have to do with the permissions on the connecting users files in their .ssh directory. Make sure their id files are only readable by themselves (400). Also, make sure that the .ssh directory and all parent directories are not writable by anyone other than root and the user. For example, their directories should have permissions like so:

```
$ ls -ld . home home/prentice home/prentice/.ssh/
drwxr-xr-x 22 root     root     4096 2011-04-28 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 2010-11-17 22:19 home
drwxr-xr-x 75 prentice prentice 4096 2011-06-15 13:56 home/prentice
drwx------  2 prentice prentice 4096 2011-04-20 08:07 home/prentice/.ssh/
```

Otherwise, ssh will reject their identity because it can be read or modified by others. Same goes for your authorized_keys file. If it can be modified by others (either directly, or by modifying the directories above it), ssh will not use it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this, I did end up checking it but perms looked good. It was actually looking for `id_rsa`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user who is trying to access the repository is trying to access from the same user account and with its corresponding rsa key ..,

For example : if you have added the root user public key to gitolite-admin and the user is trying to access from his sudo user account it woudnt work ..,